# Generic vector in VHDL, with position of assignment determined by variable

Tags: vhdl

I have a simple state machine written in VHDL. Size of every vector and variable is determined by a generic constant "n". The idea is: when I change "n", I want to immediately be able to synthesize. Part of the design is a vector in "1 of N" code.

Ports & signals definitions:

```
tester: out std_logic_vector(n-1 downto 0); -- port
signal I: integer range 0 to n-1:=0;  -- signal
```

What I have:

```
process(I)
begin
    if I=0 then
        tester<="0001";
        elsif I=1 then
        tester<="0010";
        elsif I=2 then
        tester<="0100";
        else
        tester<="1000";
    end if;
end process;
```

This obviously works only for n=4.
What I want:

```
process(I)
begin
    tester<=(I=>'1', others=>'0');
end process;
```

This does not synthesize however, due to "choice is not constant" error. I is changed by one of the states and it can be changed in any pattern, hence the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead you can do:

```
process(I)
begin
    tester    <= (others => '0');
    tester(I) <= '1';
end process;
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you. I feel kind of dumb, not trying this out earlier. Out of curiosity - why does this syntax work, and the other "  tester<=(I=>'1', others=>'0');" does not?

Comment: Index must be constant, probably to simplify; for example how to handle if doing `(a => '1', b => '0', ...)`, and a and b are sometimes the same; then priority should be defined.  Writing as sequential statements handles the issue about priority using otherwise defined constructions.